# Theoretical approach in active noise suppression

Tags: java, algorithm, audio, signal-processing

Hypothesis: I've 2 recording devices, microphone 1 is recording the sound I'm interested in and some noise, microphone 2 is recording only the noise.
What's the basic approach for removing the noise from file 1? Can I simply remove unwanted frequencies, after analyzing file 1? 
Do you know any useful java library?

Comment: A noise is represented by a stochastic process. Under the file 1 you have a _realization_ of the noise plus the useful part of the signal. If the file 2 contains exactly the representation of the noise that is found mixed with the signal in file 1, you just have to remove it from the whole signal of the file 1.

Comment: Thank you, Rerito. Just as I imagined. This "subtraction" has to be made in the frequencies domain, minding the amplitudes, and for each signal sample?

Comment: Fourier's transform is linear. Given that, you can perform the substraction either in the frequencies domain or either in the temporal domain. Note that for this to be valid you need to be sure that the noise realization recorded by micro 2 is _EXACTLY_ the same as the one recorded with the "useful signal" by micro 1. Otherwise, consider filtering techniques as suggested by Alexey :)

Comment: Thank you again. One last question: What happens if the noise is stronger than the useful signal? Does this method work? Or the waves of noise completely cover useful ones?

Comment: If you know exactly the noise signal, you won't be bothered as long as it is low enough to avoid overflow since your samples are stored in a finite interval (let's say 32-bit integers for example). If the noise is too high, you won't be able to recover your signal because of this overflow. A little example : say the max for a sample is 255, but your signal + noise is 270 -> the sampler is saturated and will give you 255 while the _true_ value is 270.

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove noise if you can distinguish between the wanted signal and the noise or if you can subtract the noise from the sum of it and the wanted signal. For the latter you may want to look into adaptive filters.

Comment: Thank you, Alexey. Do adaptive filters also work with non-periodic noise?

Comment: Periodicity or lack of thereof isn't a problem.

Comment: Perfect! I was worried about speed of convergence on non-periodic signals, like sudden noises